# jQuery Ajax print data on different page

Tags: jquery, ajax, output

I have pair of ajax function call fetching remote data and printing the output onto the same page.

However, it's been decided the output needs to be on a separate from the input. So, there will be a small form to receive input from any page on my site but the ajax generated results have to be printed out on a results page.

Is this possible, and how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Post the input form data to the next page;

Grab the data on that page and perform the AJAX call;

Show results;